# How effecient is Induction stove's heat diffuser

Tags: stove, electric-heat

I have been going through different stoves.

- Gas hob
- Electric(Coil) hob
- Induction hob

*Gas* is only 45% efficient and rest of the heat gets wasted
*Electric* hob is only 70% efficient and rest gets wasted
*Induction* hob seems to be 95% efficient

*Gas* hob -> any shape of vessels can be used
**Electric** hob -> Flat bottom vessels is required
*Induction* hob -> The bottom needs to be flat and electro magnetic like cast iron or cast iron enamel.

When I weigh in lots of factors , I prefer induction hob.

But I can not throw all the existing vessels and buy new ones.

So I am thinking to buy a heat diffuser(made of electro magnetic materials) and use my flat bottom vessels.

My question is how energy efficient it is , would it have the same energy efficiency of induction stove or electric(coil) hob.

or If I invest in Induction stove compatible vessels , then would it be used with gas or electric(coil) hob ?

Can someone elaborate me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: For efficiency, you'd probably be back to solid-plate electric levels, not even coil-plate; you're introducing a massive break in the heat transfer. Efficiency aside, gas is still by far the more economical cooktop, purely financially. See https://www.trustedreviews.com/explainer/can-induction-hobs-save-you-money-4230890 - though the prices are out of date after this year's staggering increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making this harder than need be. As long as your "vessels" (BTW on this side of the pond a vessel would be a ship!), anyway if they are stainless steel or cast iron, they are good to go on an induction cooktop or "hob" as you Brits would say.  Copper and Aluminum won't work. I guess you could use a ferrous plate that would get heated by induction, but you'd lose a LOT of the efficiency of directly heating the pot (vessel) via induction.

**Any induction ready pot is perfectly OK to use with a normal gas or electric burner, there is no issue there.**

You could "split the difference" and buy a few pots (vessels) that are induction ready and use them most of the time, and use your older ones with the ferrous plates you suggested when needed. I wouldn't worry about energy efficiency if they aren't used all that much.

I've cooked at my church for large feedings in a commercial class kitchen.  We have 4 high power (3,500 watt, 240 volt) induction burners and they are awesome to work with.   In my home I have a gas range and one thing I really don't like about it is the amount of heat escaping as well as that it's heating up the sides of the pot.  It's great for cooking with a large wok, or other large pots, but it's a pain with small ones because it burns the food bc it gets so hot  on the sides of the pot.  I've used a plate diffuser to minimize the effect, but it's not ideal.

My final comment here is go with what you want.  Cooking doesn't take that much energy so that shouldn't be a big consideration unless you're running a restaurant.

Getting philosophical for just a sec: Buy what makes you happy, life is short.

I'm sorry this is a largely opinion based answer. but it is what it is. Hopefully I don't get snipped or DV'd for this.